# Django, login form in home pages and others?

Tags: django, django-forms

i want to know how ill show the Form Login in the home pages and others?

Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put an [AuthenticationForm](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.1/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L54) on your context in any template.

If you use a RequestContext on all your templates (like you most likely should be), you could use a [context processor](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#id1) which always made this form available.